# External access to the docker containers

Tags: unix, docker, nginx, networking, containers

Is it possible to make docker containers (network) visible for another computers in local network without exposing ports to the host machine where containers placed?[image]

I have a local network that contains several machines. One of these (192.168.1.10) has docker containers (dns, nginx, mysql) and also this machine has nginx and mysql installed on itself.

I want to get access to the dns/nginx from another machines in the local network. Is it possible without exposing ports to the host machine?

p.s. excuse me for my english

Comment: nginx/mysql placed on the machine have to stay private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using DNAT (destination NAT) internally. You will need a layer 3 device that does this though.

Example: you create a "VIP" 192.168.1.111 on port XYZ. This will be NATed to the IP address of 192.168.1.10 on port say 53 (for DNS) or another port of your choice.